# How to declare a common variable for jquery and Angular 2 Typescript

Tags: jquery, angular

I have to store value from jquery and use in typescript function .

somevaiable=jQuery(this).closest('li').attr('id')

Answer (score 1):

This type of coding is not encourage by Angular 2.

But if you really want to do it you can declare it in the script tag of your HTML document, after that use it in your typescript file like this:

```js
declare var somevaiable:any;

class MyClass {
  
  onClick() {
    $(somevaiable).hide();
  }
}
```

But this type of coding is not encourage, you even don't want to modify the html of Angular app like this.

This is a caution from Angular.io website:

> Relying on direct DOM access creates tight coupling between your application and rendering layers which will make it impossible to separate the two and deploy your application into a web worker.